# Disable catalog search module - Magento 2.2.2 EE

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, search, catalogsearch

we are trying to disable the modules "Magento_Search & Magento_CatalogSearch" because we are using algolia search not default magento search. But, we can't disable the module, it has dependency module(Staging), we have run the below command to disable the all the dependency modules as well.

```
bin/magento mo:dis Magento_Search Magento_CatalogSearch Magento_CatalogImportExportStaging Magento_CatalogStaging Magento_AdvancedSearch Magento_CatalogStaging Magento_ConfigurableProductStaging Magento_Elasticsearch Magento_Solr Magento_BundleStaging Magento_DownloadableStaging
```

After that setup upgrade throws the below error 
https://nimb.ws/zOwryM

please any help?

The purpose of disabling Magento catalog search is it creates so many hits of **search_tmp_*** table, it slow down the Mysql server.